# What is the fastest way to add and drop rows to a dataframe taking into account time (to track stocks in a portfolio)?

Tags: python, pandas, portfolio

I have a dataframe which contains a number of stocks that make up a portfolio. As time progresses, some of these stocks are sold (hence dropped from the df) and others are bought (hence added to the df), so the dataframe changes over time. I would like to track the portfolio with its stocks over time as stocks are added and dropped.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

initial_pf = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["stock1", "stock2", "stock3", "stock4", "stock5"]})




transactions = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2016-11-24", "2016-12-22", "2017-02-09", "2017-02-09", "2017-02-09",
                                      "2017-02-14", "2017-02-22"],
                             "name": ["stock7", "stock1", "stock2", "stock4", "stock8", "stock9", "stock3"],
                             "type": ["buy", "sell", "sell", "sell", "buy", "buy", "sell"]})




trade_dates = transactions.date.unique()

>>> initial_portfolio
      name
0   stock1
1   stock2
2   stock3
3   stock4
4   stock5


>>> transactions
          date  name    type
0   2016-11-24  stock7  buy
1   2016-12-22  stock1  sell
2   2017-02-09  stock2  sell
3   2017-02-09  stock4  sell
4   2017-02-09  stock8  buy
5   2017-02-14  stock9  buy
6   2017-02-22  stock3  sell
```

My current approach works but is too slow, since I have trading data for several hundred days.

```
current_pf = initial_pf

for date in trade_dates:
        current_pf = current_pf.reset_index(drop=True)
        # add stocks that are bought on this date
        buys = transactions[(transactions.date == date) & (transactions.type == "buy")][["name"]]
        current_pf = pd.concat([current_pf, buys])

        # drop stocks that are sold on this date
        sells = transactions[(transactions.date == date) & (transactions.type == "sell")][["name"]]
        current_pf = current_pf[~current_pf.ISIN.isin(list(it.chain.from_iterable(sells.values.tolist())))]
```

This should return:

```
>>> current_pf
     name
1  stock5
2  stock7
3  stock8
4  stock9
```

Is there any better way of doing this? Since I ultimately want to calculate the performance of the portfolio (i.e. add price data for every day), I need to be able to look at the portfolio over time and can't just drop all the stocks that are ever sold and add all those that are bought.

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you post your ideal output?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing sample input and output, but it sounds like `current_pf = current_pf[~sells]` might work, boolean masking the dataframe with the tilde to invert the lookup

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I added the sample input and output

Comment: @G.Anderson This unfortunately doesn't work since when I add price data for each day, it's not possible to calculate the performance. 

As far as I can tell it's only possible through an iterative process since I need to track the prices iteratively as well.

Comment: Why not stock 7?

Comment: @ALollz you're right... The error occured because I dropped the sales by index in the last line of the loop but forgot to reset it in every iteration. I fixed the error. Thanks!